# How to position text on an image while sending Email via smtp

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp, webmail

I have a requirement of sending an email with embedded image and some text on top of it. The text can change from one mail to another, so it is a dynamic content, while the image is static. I am using `WebMail.Send()` in ASP.Net MVC to send this email by passing in below html to body parameter.

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;width:460px;height:560px;">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/Resources/Images/mail-message.png" alt="Mail Body Image" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; " />
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 45%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); text-align: center; min-width: 60%; height:45%; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #1DCDA3;">
        <div>
            <span style="color:gray;font-size:18px;">
                Thanks for contacting us.<br />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that even though it is mentioned that the outer element is a container with position:relative and inner elements have `position:absolute`, with corresponding `top:0` and `top:45%`, the text in inner div in the sent mail is always displaying below the image and not 45% from the top of outer div. This works totally fine in my local machine, but seems to break when sent as a mail. The question is how to make sure the text is aligned relative to top container in the mail?

**Note:** My smtp server is gmail.

**Edit1:** On inspect element on mail html, I found that the tags are stripped of `position` attributes. I think that is the cause. I am not sure why this happens. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If possible, add a fiddle

Comment: Actually, the issue is not with html. It is fine when seen on local machine/browser. Only when viewed in a mail, it seems to be having the issue.

Comment: Please see Edit1 above.

Comment: email clients do not support HTML to full extend, if you really must position it, then how about putting the info directly on the image (DrawImage, DrawText), while adding the text you want to sent to the alt attribute of the image (as you are doing now already). Don't forget that outlook, thunderbird & webmail clients do not share a common layout engine (everything can look partly different). Try to avoid using to complex html structures in emails

Comment: The text can change from mail to mail so I need to dynamically generate it. Is there a basic but common solution that works on all mail clients (atleast web based).

Comment: You could try to rewrite everything with only using the table layout, you could fill a cell of your table with a background image, and add the text inside the cell. You could get some tips here http://group-mail.com/html-email/tips-to-create-html-email-that-works-with-all-email-clients-part-1/

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Thanks.